# How do I concatenate files in Python?

Tags: python, file, mp3

I have multiple (between 40 and 50) MP3 files that I'd like to concatenate into one file.  What's the best way to do this in Python?

Use [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module to loop through each line of each file and write it to an output file?  Outsource to windows [`copy`](http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm) command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27077437/1157720

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Putting the bytes in those files together is easy... however I am not sure if that will cause a continuous play - I think it might if the files are using the same bitrate, but I'm not sure.

```
from glob import iglob
import shutil
import os

PATH = r'C:\music'

destination = open('everything.mp3', 'wb')
for filename in iglob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.mp3')):
    shutil.copyfileobj(open(filename, 'rb'), destination)
destination.close()
```

That will create a single "everything.mp3" file with all bytes of all mp3 files in C:\music concatenated together.

If you want to pass the names of the files in command line, you can use `sys.argv[1:]` instead of `iglob(...)`, etc.

Comment: you don't need fullname step there, glob is already producing absolute filenames.

Comment: and you can use iglob, instead of glob

Comment: I have no clue if it will cause continuous play or not - guess I'll find out - and maybe ask another question about it...haha.

Comment: This solution does impact continuous play - in that it doesn't happen.  There's some skipping in the spots where MP3s were joined.  This is fine for my application though.

Comment: What does the `r` in `r'C:\music'` do?

Comment: Is it just me or is there a colon missing on the for loop line?

Comment: Shouldn't the destination's file mode be set to 'a' - append?

Comment: You can also use: with open('everything.mp3', 'wb') as destination: - and let it close itself in the end

Answer (score 35):

Just to summarize (and steal from [nosklo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001538/how-do-i-concatenate-files-in-python/1001587#1001587)), in order to concatenate two files you do:

```
destination = open(outfile,'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(open(file1,'rb'), destination)
shutil.copyfileobj(open(file2,'rb'), destination)
destination.close()
```

This is the same as:

```
cat file1 file2 > destination
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but for some reason I just get the first file, and not the second file appended. Both files are mp4

Comment: Works fine for me! You can do this with one line less by using a with statement.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm. I won't use "lines". Quick and dirty use

```
outfile.write( file1.read() )
outfile.write( file2.read() )
```

;)

Answer (score 2):

Improving on Clint and nosklo, knowing context manager, I find it cleaner to write this:

```
import shutil
import pathlib

source_files = pathlib.Path("My_Music").rglob("./*.mp3")
with open("concatenated_music.mp3", mode="wb") as destination:
    for file in source_files:
        with open(file, mode="rb") as source:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, destination)
```