# reading file names from a list and then appending them does not append files

Tags: python, list, pandas, file, file-copying

I have a list contains names of the files.

I want to append content of all the files into the first file, and then copy that file(first file which is appended) to new path.

This is what I have done till now: 
This is part of code for appending (I have put a reproducable program in the end of my question please have a look on that:).

```
if (len(appended) == 1):
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, appended[0]), out_path_tempappendedfiles)
else:

    with open(appended[0],'a+') as myappendedfile:
        for file in appended:
                myappendedfile.write(file)
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, myappendedfile.name), out_path_tempappendedfiles)
```

this one will run successfully and copy successfully but it does not append files it just keep the content of the first file.

I have also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files) it did not raises error but did not append files. so the same code except instead of using `write` I used `shutil.copyobject`

```
with open(file,'rb') as fd:
shutil.copyfileobj(fd, myappendedfile)
```

the same thing happend.

**Update1**
This is the whole code:

Even with the update it still does not append:

```
import os

import pandas as pd
d = {'Clinic Number':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'date':['2015-05-05','2015-05-05','2015-05-05','2015-05-05','2016-05-05','2017-05-05'],'file':['1a.txt','1b.txt','1c.txt','2.txt','4.txt','5.txt']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.sort_values(['Clinic Number', 'date'], inplace=True)
df['row_number'] = (df.date.ne(df.date.shift()) | df['Clinic Number'].ne(df['Clinic Number'].shift())).cumsum()

import shutil
path= 'C:/Users/sari/Documents/fldr'
out_path_tempappendedfiles='C:/Users/sari/Documents/fldr/temp'

for rownumber in df['row_number'].unique():
    appended = df[df['row_number']==rownumber]['file'].tolist()
    if (len(appended) == 1):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, appended[0]), out_path_tempappendedfiles)
    else:
        with open(appended[0],'a') as myappendedfile:
            for file in appended:
                fd=open(file,'r')
                myappendedfile.write('\n'+fd.read())
                fd.close()

        Shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, myappendedfile.name), out_path_tempappendedfiles)
```

Would you please let me know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this how I resolve it.
that was very silly mistake:| not joining the basic path to it. 
I changed it to use `shutil.copyobj` for the performance purpose, but the problem only resolved with this:

```
os.path.join(path,file)
```

before adding this I was actually reading from the file name in the list and not joining the basic path to read from actual file:|

```
for rownumber in df['row_number'].unique():
    appended = df[df['row_number']==rownumber]['file'].tolist()
    print(appended)
    if (len(appended) == 1):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, appended[0]), new_path)
    else:
        with open(appended[0], "w+") as myappendedfile:
            for file in appended:
                with open(os.path.join(path,file),'r+') as fd:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(fd, myappendedfile, 1024*1024*10)
                    myappendedfile.write('\n')
        shutil.copy(appended[0],new_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this, and if the size of files are to large to load, you can use readlines as instructed in [Python append multiple files in given order to one big file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509872/python-append-multiple-files-in-given-order-to-one-big-file)

```
import os,shutil
file_list=['a.txt', 'a1.txt', 'a2.txt', 'a3.txt']
new_path=

with open(file_list[0], "a") as content_0:
    for file_i in file_list[1:]:
        f_i=open(file_i,'r')
        content_0.write('\n'+f_i.read())
        f_i.close()
shutil.copy(file_list[0],new_path)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Thats very weird but it did not appended yet. I will update with my whole code, its the same except I have other columns so I queried part of that based on the conditions I have

Comment: your code not appending the content of the files rather the names of the files

Comment: That's interesting, I makeit right in my simple tasks. Whatever, I find you have worked it out in the latter answer～