# python joining two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have two .csv files, `headers.csv` and `corrected.csv`. The`headers.csv` has all the headers, and the `corrected.csv` is just a bunch of organized data.

```
headers.csv:           
displacement, load, cputime, ...

corrected.csv:            
-990.478170,-0.000026,15:08:06, ...              
-990.038170,-0.000026,15:08:06, ...

The end goal is to be like this example:      
displacement,load,cputime, ...          
-990.478170,-0.000026,15:08:06, ...              
-990.038170,-0.000026,15:08:06, ...
```

What I have:

```
headers = [x for x in csv.reader(open('headers.csv', 'rb'))]
writer = csv.writer(open('merged.csv', 'wb'))
writer.writerow(headers)
for row in csv.reader(open('corrected.csv', 'rb')):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

The result, however, is that `"['displacement', 'load', 'cputime', ...]"` is all written to column A while I want displacement in column A, load in column B, cputime in column C, etc. I also want to get rid of the `', ", [], and whitespace`so the end result is exactly like my example above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you not just concatenate the files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001538/how-do-i-concatenate-files-in-python. This SO post will probably answer your question.

Comment: Using python to concatenate the files seems overkill - `cat headers.csv corrected.csv > merged.csv`

Comment: Wow, that definitely is a lot easier. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a single row with comma delimited column names, try: `headers = next(csv.reader(open('headers.csv')))`

Answer (score 2):

Using python to concatenate the files seems overkill -

```
cat headers.csv corrected.csv > merged.csv
```

If you have to/ for some reason want to use Python, Jon Clements has the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line you are creating a list (a comprehension list) with all the lines in headers.csv, that's why you have the [], etc.

Try with this (from the top of my mind):

```
headers = csv.reader(open('headers.csv', 'rb'))[0]
```

Which should return the first row only.

Comment: Try running this... (bearing in mind `csv.reader` is a generator)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just hide the fact that you have multiple files from the csv module:

```
import csv

def cat(*files):
    for f in files:
        with open(f) as fobj:
            for line in fobj:
                yield line

writer = csv.writer(open('merged.csv', 'wb'))
for row in csv.reader(cat('headers.csv', 'corrected.csv')):
    writer.writerow(row)
```