# Joining multiple CSV Files

Tags: python, unix

I have a folder with multiple csv files. Every file consists of a date and a value column. I would like to merge all files into one where the first column consists of the value date (which is the same for each file) and the other columns are populated by the values of each single vile i.e. (date, value_file1, value_file2...)

Any suggestions on how this could be achieved via a simple python script or maybe evan through a unix command?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [python joining two csv files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786094/python-joining-two-csv-files)

Comment: the columns of the 2nd files are simply appended to the columns of the first. i want the columns of the 2nd file to be place in a new column in the merged file not appended to the current columns.

Comment: This isn't totally clear - can you explain more clearly what the input csv files look like? Where/when are the dates the same?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using a tool like [csvkit's csvjoin](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/tutorial/3_power_tools.html#csvjoin-merging-related-data)

```
pip install csvkit
$ csvjoin --help
usage: csvjoin [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
               [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z MAXFIELDSIZE] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-v] [-l]
               [--zero] [-c COLUMNS] [--outer] [--left] [--right]
               [FILE [FILE ...]]

Execute a SQL-like join to merge CSV files on a specified column or columns.

positional arguments:
  FILE                  The CSV files to operate on. If only one is specified,
                        it will be copied to STDOUT.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DELIMITER, --delimiter DELIMITER
                        Delimiting character of the input CSV file.
  -t, --tabs            Specifies that the input CSV file is delimited with
                        tabs. Overrides "-d".
  -q QUOTECHAR, --quotechar QUOTECHAR
                        Character used to quote strings in the input CSV file.
  -u {0,1,2,3}, --quoting {0,1,2,3}
                        Quoting style used in the input CSV file. 0 = Quote
                        Minimal, 1 = Quote All, 2 = Quote Non-numeric, 3 =
                        Quote None.
  -b, --doublequote     Whether or not double quotes are doubled in the input
                        CSV file.
  -p ESCAPECHAR, --escapechar ESCAPECHAR
                        Character used to escape the delimiter if --quoting 3
                        ("Quote None") is specified and to escape the
                        QUOTECHAR if --doublequote is not specified.
  -z MAXFIELDSIZE, --maxfieldsize MAXFIELDSIZE
                        Maximum length of a single field in the input CSV
                        file.
  -e ENCODING, --encoding ENCODING
                        Specify the encoding the input CSV file.
  -S, --skipinitialspace
                        Ignore whitespace immediately following the delimiter.
  -v, --verbose         Print detailed tracebacks when errors occur.
  -l, --linenumbers     Insert a column of line numbers at the front of the
                        output. Useful when piping to grep or as a simple
                        primary key.
  --zero                When interpreting or displaying column numbers, use
                        zero-based numbering instead of the default 1-based
                        numbering.
  -c COLUMNS, --columns COLUMNS
                        The column name(s) on which to join. Should be either
                        one name (or index) or a comma-separated list with one
                        name (or index) for each file, in the same order that
                        the files were specified. May also be left
                        unspecified, in which case the two files will be
                        joined sequentially without performing any matching.
  --outer               Perform a full outer join, rather than the default
                        inner join.
  --left                Perform a left outer join, rather than the default
                        inner join. If more than two files are provided this
                        will be executed as a sequence of left outer joins,
                        starting at the left.
  --right               Perform a right outer join, rather than the default
                        inner join. If more than two files are provided this
                        will be executed as a sequence of right outer joins,
                        starting at the right.

Note that the join operation requires reading all files into memory. Don't try
this on very large files.
```