# Concatenate tab-delimited txt files vertically

Tags: python

input1, input2, output are tab-delimited txt files.

If input1 is

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

and input2 is

```
e r t
```

then I would want output to be

```
a b c
1 2 3
e r t
```

I tried to concatenate files using python by learning from [Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

I tried

```
filenames = ['input1.txt', 'input2.txt']
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

and then tried

```
filenames = ['input1.txt', 'input2.txt']
import fileinput
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fileinput.input(filenames):
        fout.write(line)
```

But both codes concatenate files horizontally, not vertically.

The codes create this:

```
a b c
1 2 3e r t
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow you; `input1` and `input2` are *concatenated*; the code samples you shared **also** concatenate the files.

Comment: replace `outfile.write(line)` with `outfile.write(line + '\n')`

Comment: `cat input1 input2 > output` would also do what you want in this case. This is precisely what concatenation is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: why not just append to input2?

Comment: @Korem I tried that, but it created another incorrect output. It adds unnecessary line break.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Is this python code?

Comment: @user3123767: no, that's a UNIX / Linux command line to be entered into your shell.

Comment: meant input1 not input2

Comment: Try my edit. It should work.

Comment: @user3123767 Martijn Peters is correct -- will also work if you are on a Mac (basically only Windows cannot do this AFAIK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of your input files is, that the last line is not terminated by a new-line-character. So you have to add it by hand:

```
filenames = ['input1.txt', 'input2.txt']
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read().rstrip() + '\n')
```

Comment: I explained my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936955/python-vertical-txt-concatenation-not-working-properly   Could you have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to line break using `\n`. Try the following code sample,

```
filenames = ['input1.txt', 'input2.txt']
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: @Letho0_ I tried that, but it created another incorrect output. It adds unnecessary line break.

Comment: 1 d e \r\n\r\n e g h \r\n 4 4 3

Comment: adds unnecessary newlines to every line.

Comment: @Leth0_ I explained my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936955/python-vertical-txt-concatenation-not-working-properly   Could you have a look at it?