# Python vertical txt concatenation not working properly

Tags: python, string-concatenation, csv

There are two solutions from [Concatenate tab-delimited txt files vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722449/concatenate-tab-delimited-txt-files-vertically)

Suppose input1 is

```
X\tY
```

input2 is

```
A\tB\r\n
C\t\r\n
```

Here, A, B, C are ordinary words and \t is tab.

If I run

```
filenames = [input1, input2]
with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read().rstrip() + '\n')
```

then I get

```
X\tY\r\n
A\tB\r\n
C
```

Suddenly \t after C disappears.

If I run

```
filenames = [input1, input2]
with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write("\n")
```

then I get

```
X\tY\r\n
A\tB\r\n
C\t\r\n
\r\n
```

I simply want to concatenate vertically. In this case, I would need this.

```
X\tY\r\n
A\tB\r\n
C\t\r\n
```

I used these two files as example inputs.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-M3FJS21UTk02Z1k/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-eWxiTmhKVTJrNjQ/edit?usp=sharing

@pavel_form

Do you mean I have to code

```
filenames = [input1, input2]
with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read().rstrip('\r\n') + '\n')
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example will work if you add parameter "what chars to strip" in rstrip call. Like this:

```
    outfile.write(infile.read().rstrip('\r\n') + '\n')
```

So, the complete example will be:

```
    filenames = [input1, input2]
    with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
        for fname in filenames:
            with open(fname) as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read().rstrip('\r\n') + '\n')
```

Comment: I tested the version I wrote on my revised question, and it works. To clarify and confirm, I edited my question to ask you if what I understood is correct.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. Will update answer to contain complete example.