# Join multiple files with python

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

Is there a better way to join files?

I have two files that I want to merge:

File 1:
AccountNo, firstName, lastName
12, Peter, Smith
14, Mary, Smith

File 2: 
AccountNo, Payment, Invoice
12, 15.00, 1000
14, 15.10, 1001

I would like to join the files into one:
AccountNo, firstName, lastName, Payment, Invoice
12, Peter, Smith, 15.00, 1000
14, Mary, Smith, 15.10, 1001

I'm using Python 3.3

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as names:
    with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as accts:
        with open('combined.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            n = n.readline()
            a = a.readline()
            outFile.write(n.replace('\n', '\t') + a)
```

Not sure this is the best way to do this, or if there is a better way to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: it is definitely not the best way as it would not even run, are your files multiple lines in exactly the same format as in your example?

Comment: What is good? What is better?

Answer (score 0):

I would check [this question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files), which may answer your question. Most answers give a similar response to your code, using `with`.