# how to append the content of one file at the of the content of another file in python

Tags: python, file

i would like to add the content of one file at the end of the content of the other file. i have let say:

```
The content of the file1 is :  james@29@458462


The content of the file2 is : marc@45@4695588
```

after appending file2 into file1 i would like to have:

```
 james@29@458462
 marc@45@4695588
```

This is the code i tried to use but it replace the content of the target file with the source file:

```
file1=open("test1.txt","a")
file2=open("test2.txt","r")
file1.write(file2.read())
```

Can i please have a way of appending at the end of one file without replacing the content of the target file?

Thank you

Comment: Try reading through examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files

Comment: Could not replicate - on 2.7.6 `'a'` mode appends to the end of the file, as expected.

Comment: The code seems to be working fine for me. Which python version are you using?

Comment: @danielfranca im using python 3.4

Comment: Can you try to use this function instead?
http://pastebin.com/277DBtAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using with when you are working with files (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) :

```
with open("test1.txt","a") as file1, open("test2.txt","r") as file2:
    for line in file2:
        file1.write('\n' + line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bash` script commands in python to append two files together as following:

```
import subprocess as S

CMD="cat file1.txt file2.txt > new.txt"
S.call([CMD],shell=True)
```

Comment: A lot of overhead to run bash from python for such a simple operation.

Comment: @danielfranca I don't think there is any overhead using bash commands. It does much better job dealing with txt files than python.

Comment: I did a test, putting in a small loop (1000 iterations), both a normal python implementation and a bash implementation, as you can see here: http://pastebin.com/4zp7r1qs

And the python one was much faster:
http://pastebin.com/pa1ytN7c

Comment: @danielfranca well I didn't measure the time but from my experience using bash script to concatenate files rows and columns is much faster than python. However, I haven't seen any where in this post is mentioned that the speed of the performance is vital for the author!