# AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute '__exit__'

Tags: python

I am trying to read from multiple input files and print the second row from each file next to each other as a table

```
import sys
import fileinput

with fileinput.input(files=('cutflow_TTJets_1l.txt ', 'cutflow_TTJets_1l.txt ')) as f:
    for line in f:
        proc(line)



def proc(line):
     parts = line.split("&") # split line into parts
     if  "&" in line:    # if at least 2 parts/columns
         print parts[1] # print column 2
```

But I get a "AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute '`__exit__`'"

Comment: As best I can tell, Python closes the files in fileinput as soon as they're done - at least the docs make no mention of needing to close them.  As such it wouldn't make sense to use a context manager with fileinput, and it wouldn't make sense to implement `__enter__` or `__exit__`

Comment: sorry, I dont see how this helps me

Comment: The solution is to not use a context manager.

Comment: What is your Python version? Is it Python 2.7? You could use `with contextlib.closing(fileinput.FileInpt(..)) as file:` on Python 2.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that as of python 2.7.10, the fileinput module does not support being used as a context manager, i.e. the `with` statement, so you have to handle closing the sequence yourself. The following should work:

```
f = fileinput.input(files=('cutflow_TTJets_1l.txt ', 'cutflow_TTJets_1l.txt '))

for line in f:
    proc(line)

f.close()
```

Note that in recent versions of python 3, you can use this module as a context manager.

---

For the second part of the question, assuming that each file is similarly formatted with an equal number of data lines of the form `xxxxxx & xxxxx`, one can make a table of the data from the second column of each data as follows:

Start with an empty list to be a table where the rows will be lists of second column entries from each file:

```
table = []
```

Now iterate over all lines in the `fileinput` sequence, using the `fileinput.isfirstline()` to check if we are at a new file and make a new row:

```
for line in f:
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
        row = []
        table.append(row)
    parts = line.split('&')
    if len(parts) > 1:
        row.append(parts[1].strip())

f.close()
```

Now `table` will be the transpose of what you really want, which is each row containing the second column entries of a given line of each file. To transpose the list, one can use `zip` and then loop over rows the transposed table, using the `join` string method to print each row with a comma separator (or whatever separator you want):

```
for row in zip(*table):
    print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: Does that close every file? Or just the last one (i.e. the other ones are closed when they are done being used)?

Comment: @Just_Newbie that's because you're using `proc` before you define it.  Reorder things

Comment: Great ! and how would it be possible to get them a a table ie the two columns side-by-side ?

Comment: @Just_Newbie That part is kind of tricky to answer without . Do both files have the same number of lines of the form `xxxx & xxxx`? If not, should there be empty places in the table? Should line 7 from the first file always match to line 7 from the second?

Comment: @Dannnno  fileinput just iterates through each file in the sequence, and only actually opens a file when `next()` is called if the end of the previous file is reached and there are still files left. `close()` just calls `nextfile()` which closes the current file (if one is open) and advances to the next file in the sequence, without actually opening it.

Comment: @EricAppelt - Yes, all input files should have the same number of lines and format match between different files

Comment: @Just_Newbie - ok, I added a solution of how this might be done using `fileinput`

Answer (score 4):

If something has `open`/`close` methods, use `contextlib.closing`:

```
import sys
import fileinput
from contextlib import closing

with closing(fileinput.input(files=('cutflow_TTJets_1l.txt ', 'cutflow_TTJets_1l.txt '))) as f:
    for line in f:
        proc(line)
```