# Concatenate .txt files. Write content in one .txt file

Tags: python, concatenation, os.walk

I have some .txt files in a folder. I need to collect their content all in one .txt file.  I'm working with Python and tried:

```
import os

rootdir = "\\path_to_folder\\"

for files in os.walk(rootdir):
    with open ("out.txt", 'w') as outfile:
         for fname in files:
             with open(fname) as infile:
                  for line in infile:
                      outfile.write(line)
```

but did not work. The 'out.txt' is generated but the code never ends. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you don't do this in the shell with `find rootdir -type f -exec cat {} + > out.txt`

Comment: Read the docs for os.walk: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: [Almost a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13613336/198633)

Comment: Could you please expand on how to do this in the shell with find rootdir -type f -exec cat {} + > out.txt? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`os.walk` returns tuples, not filenames:

```
with open ("out.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for fname in files:
             with open(os.path.join(root, fname)) as infile:
                  for line in infile:
                      outfile.write(line)
```

Also you should open outfile in the beginning, not in each loop.

Comment: Unfortunately even opening 'outfile' in the beginning I couldn't solve the problem: the loop never ends

Comment: Maybe there are too many files in your directory, try with test data.

Comment: It was a good idea to try with test data. The loop eventually ended, but the problem is not solved yet. I opened 6 files of around 150KG and my 'out.txt' is 923,700KG.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. The generated 'out.txt' file is just 151KB.

```
file_list = os.listdir("\\path_to_folder\\")

with open('out.txt', 'a+') as outfile:
for fname in file_list:
    with open(fname) as infile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Thanks everybody.