# Python - For loop problems

Tags: python

I am trying to create a loop to go through ~3,000 .xml files to search for certain lines and print out into one txt file.

My original code which i am able to use on one xml is:

```
my_file = open(r'C:\temp\20160309_test_xml\out.txt', 'w')

with open(r'C:\temp\20160309_test_xml\test.xml', 'r') as file:
    for name, lines in enumerate(file, 1):
        if "OBJNAM" in lines:
            my_file.write(file.next())
with open(r'C:\temp\20160309_test_xml\test.xml', 'r') as file:
    for number,  line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if "srfres" in line:
            my_file.write(file.next())
file.close()
```

I've attempted to create a loop for this but the output txt is printing blank:

```
import glob
import os

path = r'C:\temp\test_xml'
xml_directory = os.path.join(path, '*.xml')
xml_list = glob.glob(xml_directory)
my_file = open(r'C:\temp\20160309_test_xml\out.txt', 'w')

for xml in xml_list:
    for name, lines in enumerate(xml, 1):
        if "OBJNAM" in lines:
            my_file.write(file.next())
for xml in xml_list:
    for number,  line in enumerate(xml, 1):
        if "srfres" in line:
            my_file.write(xml.next())

my_file.close()
print
```

Comment: doesn't look like you are opening all the files.

Comment: What is .next() and why you use it? Should not you use the "lines" var?

Comment: i am using .next() to pull out a line below the word i am searching for as each text file has the same word in but not on the same line each time eg.   i am searching OBJNAME to pull out the attribute name (Value):
    `<Attribute name="OBJNAM">`
    `<Value>2014 HI1447 Blakeney Overfalls 1m CUBE</Value>` (separate lines)

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13613336/198633

Answer (score 0):

```
my_files = os.listdir("/all_files/") #put your input directory here
my_writer = open(r'C:\temp\20160309_test_xml\out.txt', 'w')
for fn in my_files:
    if not fn.endswith(".xml"):
         continue
    with open(fn, 'r') as f: #open and read from every xml file
         for line in f:
             if "OBJNAM" in line or "srfres" in line:
                  my_writer.write(line)
my_writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can try with list comprehension

```
[(name,lines) for name,lines in enumerate(xml_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not opening files in your loop and instead you're iterating over paths.

I have few suggestions regarding your code:

You can iterate over file lines like that:

```
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line
```

Also, when dealing with xml files, maybe you could use `xml` lib.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os

xmlDir = r'C:\temp\test_xml'
xmlFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(xmlDir, "*.xml"))
outfilepath = r'C:\temp\20160309_test_xml\out.txt'
keywords = ['OBJNAM', 'srfres']

copy = False
with open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
    for fpath in xmlFiles:
        with open(fpath) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                if copy: outfile.write(line)

                if any (w in line for w in keywords):
                    copy = True
                    continue
                else:
                    copy = False
                    continue
```