# join rows of different files in python

Tags: python, join, row

If text1

```
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1
```

text2

```
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
4 5
2 3 4 5 6
```

and text3

```
8 9 10 11
9
6 7 8
7
```

What is the most direct way to join the rows of the different files together and write the resulting text to a file?

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I tried looping through the files and use `file.read()` but this merges the files vertically

Comment: Did you try pandas ?

Comment: @Wen: Do you mean using pd.concatenate?

Comment: Yes, pd.concat here

Comment: It can be done without pandas too. You should have at least tried something.

Comment: @roganjosh: Yes. I tried looping through the files and use file.read() and tried other options (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files), but they all merge files vertically

Comment: No need for advanced tools. Just a unix commend: `paste -d' ' text1 text2 text3`

Comment: @liliscent: Thanks! But can I use that in a .py script? Or do you mean doing it via the command line?

Comment: @HappyPy It's for commend line. You can do it in Python as well. `result = Popen(('paste', '-d ', 'text1', 'text2', 'text3'))`. But if you're already writing Python script, I recommend you write pure Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to merge the lines in the text files:

```
with open('text1', 'r') as f1:
    t1 = f1.readlines()

with open('text2', 'r') as f2:
    t2 = f2.readlines()

with open('text3', 'r') as f3:
    t3 = f3.readlines()

for item in zip(t1,t2,t3):
    print ' '.join([line.strip() for line in item])
```

result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

**Edit**: More generalized solution:

```
files = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']

contents = []

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as fn:
        contents.append(fn.readlines())

for entry in zip(contents):
    for item in entry:
        print ' '.join([line.strip() for line in item])
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make this more general, like defining a list of files at the beginning, instead of having to write "with open..." for each file?

Comment: Surely there is a way, but I can't think of one this moment. If I figure one out, I'll post it.

Comment: @HappyPy see edit in updated answer, it's not very clean or optimized, but it seems to work.

Comment: @davedwards Depending on how many files OP is working with (and/or the size of them), using `readlines` on each one might cause the script to run out of memory though. Looks like the same potential issue in the other answer as well.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce True, especially if it were to become an issue for others using this approach in future

Answer (score 2):

I think pandas is easier, but you can do it without pandas.

```
file_names = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt']
res = []
for name in file_names:
    with open(name,'rb') as f:
        res.append(f.readlines())

res = [(' '.join(map(lambda row:row.strip(),line)) + '\n') for line in zip(*res)]
```

output:

```
['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11\n',
 '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n',
 '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n',
 '1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n']
```