# How to Concatenate Multiple rtf files while maintaining formatting

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, rtf

I am using a Mac with OS 10.13.

I have 56 formatted RTF files that must be combined into one RTF file without losing formatting.  I don't mind renaming the files to part1.rtf, part2.rtf, etc. if that helps automate the task.

I've got Word 2016 for Mac and have the Developer tab activated, and I also have Python installed.  I have a conceptual understanding of programming and scripting, so I could follow directions, but I don't have the knowledge necessary to *write* a script or program to do this.

I guess I'm hoping that this is a common enough problem that one of y'all has got a solution already.

Comment: Sorry that someone downvoted this, (wasn't me), but here's a similar question, with 100+ upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files - Hopefully the answers in there will help you get started. Have a go at writing your first python script, and see how you get on. Make sure you backup your files before doing this (just copy them to another directory for safe keeping). Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I can tell, that thread is about concatenating .txt files, or plain text, which is not what I have.  I have .rtf files with complex formatting that has to be maintained after the concatenation. What am I missing?

Comment: Not my favorite approach, but how about automating an `open-select all-copy-switch to master-goto end-paste-switch back-close` macro? You can record the macro for one iteration and then modify it so that it will process all your files.