# How to appending multiple file context with path of the file in single file using python

Tags: python

I have multiple files in path `/opt/data/file1.txt file2.txt` `file3.txt`

I want to append all context in the single file like path `/opt/alltxt.txt`
file content like

```
path /opt/data/file1.txt
"file1 context"    

path /opt/data/file2.txt
"file2 context"

path /opt/data/file2.txt
"file2 context"
```

Comment: /opt/alltxt.txt This file should contain all those paths?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It may help you

```
import os
import glob
def remove_newlines(fname):
    flist = open(fname).readlines()
    return [s.rstrip('\n') for s in flist]

my_file=open("all_content_file.txt", "w")
for i in glob.glob('./*.txt'):
    my_file.write("path")
    my_file.write(os.path.abspath(i))
    my_file.write(" ")
    for j in remove_newlines(os.path.abspath(i)):
        my_file.write(j)
        my_file.write(" ")
    my_file.write("\n")
```