# Concatenation of Text Files (.txt files) with list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

Suppose I am having two text files 1.txt and 2.txt

The content of `1.txt` as:

```
['Hi', 'I', 'am']
```

and

The content of `2.txt` as:

```
['a', 'boy']
```

How to join the same and write the same into a new file in time efficient manner, say `3.txt`, which should look like this:

```
['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'boy']
```

I have tried:

```
import os

file_list = os.listdir("path")
with open('out.txt', 'a+') as outfile:
   for fname in file_list:
       with open(fname) as infile:
          outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Comment: You can use `list1.extend(list2)`. Here is the detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/7965185

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
inputText = []
for file in ['1.txt','2.txt']:
    with open(file,'r') as file:
        inputText.extend(file.readlines()+['\n'])
with open ('3.txt','w') as output:
    for line in inputText:
        output.write(line)
```

or

```
with open ('3.txt','w') as output:
    for file in ['1.txt','2.txt']:
        with open(file,'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                output.write(line)
            output.write('\n')
```

Edited to your comment:

```
import re
inputList = []
for file in ['1.txt','2.txt']:
    with open(file,'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            inputList.extend(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9,]+', '', line).split(","))
print(inputList)
with open('3.txt','w') as outfile:
    for line in inputList:
        outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks Van! How to specify the output in single list like `['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'boy']`. The output yielded from your suggestion results in separated lists like ['Hi', 'I', 'am',] and ['a', 'boy']

Comment: Thanks @Van. Your edited answer yields the output in one list like: `["['Hi', 'I', 'am']", "['a', 'boy']"]`. What I need the output to be displayed in a single list not list of lists. The desired output should be in somewhat this format: `['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'boy']`.

Comment: Tested it on both python 2 & 3. Hope it does what you want now. 'inputList' in the third codeshippet should be the list you want.

Comment: Sorry. I am getting the output as per your suggestion using `codeshippet -3` as `["['Hi', 'I', 'am']", "['a', 'boy']"]`. But, I want the output as: `['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'boy']`. There should not be any intermediate lists in between. All the strings should be clubbed into a single list.

Comment: How does your txt file look, is it a single lined sentence which you want to split in words? Or is it multilined?

Comment: The content of txt file is shown above. It's exactly the same.

Comment: My bad, I thought you read in a multilined text and the text above was your list in python. Ill edit my code. I used some string editing to make it a python list like you want, but it's often easier to just save it as plain text in the txt file, and it will turn into a python list when you read it in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185151/discussion-between-m-s-and-van-der-zon-stef).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But does there exist any way apart from using `re` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html) for loading json from file, so you will have a list insead of a string.
You just have to concatenate list using `+` operator and save it:

```
import json

final_result = []
for file in ["1.txt", "2.txt"]:
    with open(file, 'r') as fd:
        final_result += json.load(fd)

with open("3.txt", 'w') as fd:
    json.dump(final_result, fd)
```

Comment: Thanks Elden!. I tried your suggestion. How to specify the CWD path!

Comment: By default, Python use your current working dir. If you want use specific path, you can add a path before the `file` variable : ``with open(path + file, 'r') as fd:``. If you want use the folder where your script are, you can use ``path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))``