# Concatenation of text files consisting list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

Suppose that I am having two text files 1.txt and 2.txt

The content of `1.txt` as:

```
[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am']]
```

and

The content of `2.txt` as:

```
[['_a', 'good'], ['boy']]
```

How to join the same and write the same into a new file in time efficient manner, say `3.txt`, which should look like this:

```
[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am'], ['_a', 'good'], ['boy']]
```

Note: I want the special characters (_) to be remain as it is.

I have tried from a previous answer of stack overflow which is mentioned in [Concatenation of Text Files (.txt files) with list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739613/concatenation-of-text-files-txt-files-with-list-in-python)

What I have tried is as follows:

```
global inputList
inputList = []
path = "F:/Try/"
def load_data():
    for file in ['1.txt', '2.txt']:
        with open(path + file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8) as infile:
           inputList.extend(infile.readlines())
    print(inputList)
load_data()
```

But I am not getting the desired output as shown in above. The output what I am getting right now is as follows:

```
["[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am']]", "[['_a', 'good'], ['boy']]"]
```

Why there is a extra (" ") in the current output of mine.

Please suggest something productive?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are trying to read an array from a file. But reading a file like this returns a string. You will have to parse the string convert it to an array. There are a lot of things going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ast
x="[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am']]"
ast.literal_eval(x)
```

output:

```
[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am']]
```

In your case:

```
import ast
global inputList
inputList = []
path = "F:/Try/"
def load_data():
    for file in ['1.txt', '2.txt']:
        with open(path + file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
           inputList.extend(ast.literal_eval(infile.readlines()))
    print(inputList)
load_data()
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use:

```
import json

with open("1.txt", "r") as t1, open("2.txt", "r") as t2, open("3.txt", "w") as t3:
    t3.write(json.dumps([eval(t1.read().strip()), eval(t2.read().strip())]))
```

---

**3.txt**

```
[[["Hi", "I"], ["I"], ["_am"]], [["_a", "good"], ["boy"]]]
```

---

Notes:

- [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)
- [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I am not that proficient in json. I will go through with your suggested links. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Do your files always look like that? You can then just remove the "outer" `[` and `]`.

```
path = "F:/Try/"

def load_data():
    result = []
    for file in ['1.txt', '2.txt']:
        with open(path + file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            result.append(infile.readline().strip()[1:-1])
    return "[" + ", ".join(result) + "]"

print(load_data())
```

Which prints

```
[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am'], ['_a', 'good'], ['boy']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xlist = ["[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am']]", "[['_a', 'good'], ['boy']]"]
ylist = []
for x in xlist:
    if x.startswith('[') and x.endswith(']'):
        ylist.append(x[1:-1])
zstring =''
for y in ylist:
    if zstring == '':
        zstring = y
    else:
        zstring += ', ' + y

print (zstring)
#['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am'], ['_a', 'good'], ['boy']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out (don't forget to put the star operator):

```
import ast
global inputList
inputList = []
path = "F:/Try/"
def load_data():
    for file in ['1.txt', '2.txt']:
        with open(path + file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
            inputList.extend(ast.literal_eval(*infile.readlines()))
    print(inputList)
load_data()
```

Comment: Thanks @TED. What is the star operator about?

Comment: Basically if you have input that is something like [[a]], the star * 'unwraps' the outermost [] so that we now have input as [a].

Answer (score 1):

If you want real efficiency, write 1.txt to 3.txt without the last character, and then write 2.txt without the first character

```
def concat1():

    with open('3.txt', 'w') as outf:
        with open('1.txt') as inf:
            outf.write(inf.read()[:-1])

        outf.write(',')

        with open('2.txt') as inf:
            outf.write(inf.read()[1:])
            
concat1()
```

gives

```
[['Hi', 'I'], ['I'], ['_am'],['_a', 'good'], ['boy']]
```