# how to combine text files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have 2 text files.

file1:

```
Good morning .
How are you today ?
```

and file2:

```
1 0 .
1 0 2 0 .
```

How can we make one text file like below:

```
Good/1 morning/0 ./.
How/1 are/0 you/2 today/0 ?/.
```

Any help?

Comment: by actually reading file and do what you want, where did you exactly stock?

Comment: `zip` will allow you to iterate over two lists simultaneously `join` is a string method that you can use to put the elements you need together. Take a look at the Python docs on reading files. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You're question as currently formulated is way too broad, please post what you're tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can split a line into a list of words based upon spaces as a breaking character:

```
>>> line1 = 'Good morning .'
>>> line1.split()
['Good', 'morning', '.']
```

You can `zip` lists together to get pairings of first, second, third elements of each list:

```
>>> line2 = '1 0 .'
>>> zipped = list(zip(line1.split(), line2.split()))
>>> zipped
[('Good', '1'), ('morning', '0'), ('.', '.')]
```

We can then format each pair into a new string:

```
>>> '{}/{}'.format(*('Good', '1'))
'Good/1'
```

We use `str.join` for each pair in the sequence.

Putting it all together:

```
with open('output', 'w') as output:
     with open('file1') as file1:
         with open('file2') as file2:
             for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
                 output_line = ' '.join('{}/{}'.format(*pair)
                                        for pair in zip(line1.split(), line2.split()))
                 output.write(output_line + '\n')
```

edit: also we could `join` each pair into a new string, which is terser:

```
>>> pair = ('Good', '1')
>>> '/'.join(pair)
'Good/1'
```

So, you would instead get:

```
output_line = ' '.join('/'.join(pair)
                       for pair in zip(line1.split(), line2.split()))
```

Note, I also added a missing `\n` character when writing to the `output` file.

Answer (score 2):

You could just read both files, format the content and then write out your content on a new file

```
# Read out the file contents
def read_file(file_path):
    lines = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
    return lines

# Merge the contents of two files
def merge_files(file1_path, file2_path, output_path='output.txt'):
    # Read and store the contents of both files
    file_1 = read_file(file1_path)
    file_2 = read_file(file2_path)

    # Create the output/merged file
    with open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
        # Iterate over the first files content
        for row_idx in range(len(file_1)):

            file_1_row = file_1[row_idx]
            file_2_row = file_2[row_idx]

            # Merge the matching row of each file
            content_row = [
                "{}/{}".format(file_1_row[word_idx], file_2_row[word_idx])
                for word_idx in range(len(file_1_row))
            ]
            # Write the merged row into the new file
            output_file.write(" ".join(content_row))
            output_file.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    merge_files('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')
    # If you need the output file in a different file
    # merge_files('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', output_path='output.txt')
```

This will generate your merged file into `output.txt` by default. This also assumes that your data is correct where the file rows match the expected count.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and store the values into `list`. Then you can do whatever you want by accesing the `list` element via `index`.

You can check this [Concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files) and for reading the file [read a file line-by-line into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740172/7965185)