# Merging multiple files into some number of files

Tags: python

I have a program which generates text files in every some seconds and within few days, the file number reaches to thousands of hundreds. I dont want to merge them into a single files because then file size reaches to over 50 Gb. But What I want is to divide and merge those smaller files into some number of files. 
For example, I have 10 files and I would like to merge first 5 files to 
`FileA.txt`, then 3 files to `FileB.txt` and rest two files to `FileC.txt`.

Is this possible to achieve in Python without copying and pasting files to folder and then merge?

Comment: It's possible. There's no reason to first copy them to another folder, just read them from where ever they reside.

Comment: It is possible. But the conditions have to be defined clearly. What criteria to divide by and what criteria to merge by? As a starting point, you can use `os.path.getsize(filepath)` to determine the size of your file as a basis for dividing and merging

Comment: @ycx I think the easier criteria would be total number of files that each merged file contain and for the last merged file can contain whatever number of files left to merge.

Comment: @martineau Do you happen to know any example or library that does this ?

Comment: You don't need any special library for that. simple google search will give you a lot of examples, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files but you still need to decide on what all files should be merged.

Comment: user3280146: There's no library for this specific sort of thing. All it takes is the standard built-ins / standard library...and some relatively straight-forward programming. Give it a try! @Sam has described the basic process in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible simply by opening each file sequentially and appending its contents to an output file, creating a new output file whenever you deem is necessary, and deleting the input files after they have been read. You should be able to do this easily with the Python standard library, though there could be packages that make the process easier that I do not know about.