# Why does my "cat" statement not work inside my Python for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, subprocess, cat

I am trying to concatenate many different log files that have the same name and are located in different directories. The filenames are in the form of `fit_objectname.log` where `objectname` varies. Since I have many pairs of these, I am attempting to accomplish this in a for loop within python, like this:

```
import re
import glob
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

new_logfiles = glob.glob('/Users/myusername/Desktop/subdir1/fit*.log')
for log in new_logfiles:
    filename = re.search(r'(fit.+?\.log)', log)[1]
    cmd = "cat /Users/myusername/Desktop/subdir1/{} /Users/myusername/Desktop/subdir2/{} >> {}_concat.log".format(filename, filename, filename[:-4])
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
```

However, the concatenation is not working. The result for each `fit_objectname_concat.log` file saved is just the contents of the log file in `subdir1`.

I've isolated my problem to the loop, since if I run this command on just one file pair (either in terminal or in the python script), it works:

```
cmd = "cat /Users/myusername/Desktop/subdir1/fit_obj1.log /Users/myusername/Desktop/subdir2/fit_obj1.log > fit_obj1_concat.log"
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
```

I've also tried adding a `time.sleep(2)` statement after each iteration in the loop, but I have the same issue. Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: If you want to use cat why not just use a shell script? Or conversely, if you want to use python why not just use python? Why are you extracting the filename out of a path only to printf it right back in? Why are you using regex instead of `os.path` in the first place? This all seems rather Rube-Goldberg-esque.

Comment: This probably isn't a dup as it doesn't answer your question, but try [using `shutil.copyfileobj()` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077437/1270789).