# Merging two text files into a single file using glob2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used this piece of code in sublime editor

```
import glob2
from datetime import datetime

filenames = glob2.glob("*.txt")
with open(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".txt", 'w') as file:
    for filename in filenames:       
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            file.write(f.read() + "\n")
```

I'm not able to get the output. Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean by 'not able to get the output'?