# Python: how to combine two .txt files into one and self-generate its .txt file

Tags: python

I wanted to combine two .txt files into another self-generated .txt file

Example:-

> Contents of File 1

abcdefg

> Contents of file 2

123456

> Self-generated .txt File in the output folder

abcdefg
123456

```
filenames = [fname1, fname2, fname3]
with open('H:\output\output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

i use this code where it can combine both and write the output but the problem is it is not auto-generated file, we have to personally create an output file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Comment: I suggest you break the problem down into smaller parts. For example, to accomplish this task, you need to open a file and read from it. You also need to open another file and write to it. If you don't know how to do either of these in Python, then you should google something like "read file python" or "write file python" for more information.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no that is not the case, I have to generate a new text file by itself by adding the contents of both the file, I lack in knowledge of generating a new file by itself by adding contents of those two files

Comment: Had you done the research that Code-Apprentice suggested, you would have found your problem entirely solved by opening a file in write mode. There is nothing different about your question that cannot, unless you're missing details, be solved by that approach.

Comment: @Appries what do you mean by generating a new file by itself? You mention auto-generating a file, is that any different? Do you want your program/script to know the name of the output file?

Comment: @roganjosh thank youuuuu.... i totally forgot i can create a .txt and then write the output file into it.

Comment: @simplycoding im sorry, i dint get the word create, by auto-generated i meant create a new file

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, you are right, I totally forgot that I could create a new file

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly – just change the `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` lines to fit the filenames of your two files if you'd like:

```py
# Open both .TXT files
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

# Read both .TXT files and put contents into variables
file1Contents = file1.read()
file2Contents = file2.read()

# Close both files
file1.close()
file2.close()

# Open new .TXT file for the resulting concatenated file
resultFile = open("result.txt","w")

# Write concatenated contents to resulting file
resultFile.write(file1Contents + file2Contents)

# Close resulting file
resultFile.close()
```

Comment: Although I have answered my own question... I'll try this

Comment: it is creating the file but not adding contents