# Python concatenate multiple files up to certain limit of lines in each one

Tags: python

I am looking for a code able to concatenate different .txt files but just up to certain number of lines in each one.

Suppose we have many text files as follows:

file1.txt:

```
AAAAA

BBBBB

CCCCC

DDDDD

EEEEE
```

file2.txt:

```
FFFFF

GGGGG

HHHHH

IIIII

JJJJJ
```

file3.txt:

```
KKKKK

LLLLL

MMMMM

NNNNN

OOOOO
```

file4.txt:

```
PPPPP

QQQQQ

RRRRR

SSSSS

TTTTT
```

How can we make one log file like below (assuming that all of them must be concatenated only up to the line number 3 -included)?

result:

```
AAAAA

BBBBB

CCCCC

FFFFF

GGGGG

HHHHH

KKKKK

LLLLL

MMMMM

PPPPP

QQQQQ

RRRRR
```

This is for Python 3.7.3. I was succesful to concatenate the files using the examples available in:

[Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

but I was not able to modify the code for a specific maximum number of lines per file.

Related code developed until now (but not successful):

```
    a = open('newfile.log', 'wb')
    with a as wfd:
            for f in glob.glob(r'*.txt'):
                    with open(f,'rb') as fd:
                            for line in fd:
                                    for line in range (0, 3):
                                            a.write(line)
```

Any help?

The obtained error message says:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'

Comment: Don't you want to use `wfd.write()` as opposed to `a.write()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to be using

```
for **line** in fd:

  for **line** in range (0, 3):
```

The second line variable overwrites the first, so line is an integer from 0..3
If you do want to do that, just use

```
a.write(str(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
import glob

limit = 3
with open('newfile.log', 'wb') as wfd:
    for f in glob.glob(r'*.txt'):
        with open(f, 'rb') as fd:
            line_count = 0
            for line in fd:
                if line_count >= limit:
                    break
                wfd.write(line)
                line_count += 1
```

Comment: `for line_count, line in enumerate(fd):` to avoid manually tracking `line_count`.

Comment: @AndrésF Here at Stack Overflow, if an answer helped you, the common practice is to [upvote the answer or to mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). The upvotes and the green checkmark indicate to others which answer solved your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

the value of `line` in the first loop, which is `bytes` since `f` is opened in binary mode, is overwritten by the second loop and becomes an `int` which is not what `write()` expects.
you can use `writelines()` to write a list of lines that you can get using `readlines()`, of course you can use slicing on `readlines()` to get only the first 3 lines:

```py
import glob

with open("newfile.log", "wb") as log:
    for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        with open(f, "rb") as fd:
            log.writelines(fd.readlines()[:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can describe the line numbers you want with a call to `range()` then you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for a more direct method:

```
from itertools import islice

max_lines = 3

with open('newfile.log', 'wb') as wfd:
    for f in glob.glob(r'*.txt'):
        with open(f, 'rb') as fd:
            wfd.writelines(islice(fd, max_lines))
```