# How to merge multiple json files into one json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have several json files that I would like to merge into one json file. The json files are in the following format:

file1:

```
{"seconds":112,"label":"1","value":{"time":15,"period":1576,"values":[1,2,3]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[1,2,3]},"size":{"type":1,"values":[-9,10,20]}}

{"seconds":115,"label":"2","value":{"time":20,"period":882,"values":[11,82,8]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[99,8,3]},"size":{"type":3,"values":[89,65,-20]}}
```

file2:

```
{"seconds":532,"label":"12","value":{"time":90,"period":4328,"values":[11,2,32]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[112,2,32]},"size":{"type":1,"values":[-23,9420,20]}} 

{"seconds":115,"label":"2","value":{"time":20,"period":882,"values":[11,82,8]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[942,6,332]},"size":{"type":32,"values":[49,125,-590]}}
```

that I would like to merge into one json file to be like the following:

```
{"seconds":112,"label":"1","value":{"time":15,"period":1576,"values":[1,2,3]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[1,2,3]},"size":{"type":1,"values":[-9,10,20]}}

{"seconds":115,"label":"2","value":{"time":20,"period":882,"values":[11,82,8]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[99,8,3]},"size":{"type":3,"values":[89,65,-20]}}

{"seconds":532,"label":"12","value":{"time":90,"period":4328,"values":[11,2,32]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[112,2,32]},"size":{"type":1,"values":[-23,9420,20]}}

{"seconds":115,"label":"2","value":{"time":20,"period":882,"values":[11,82,8]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[942,6,332]},"size":{"type":32,"values":[49,125,-590]}}
```

I have tried:

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merge.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

But that gave me 'raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 333)' Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Do you need the empty line in between each json string?

Comment: @EnoGergurin Not an empty line, just to have each string be on its own line would be ideal.

Comment: @EnoGerguri I tried that, and got 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str''

Comment: It`s not enough to read the raw files and join them together? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-merge-multiple-files-into-a-new-file-using-Python

Comment: I agree with @Namba, just concatenate the files. Since it looks like the data is json lines format, you can completely ignore the json nature and treat them as lines of plain text. So standard unix command-line tools are sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python concatenate text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Comment: @Namba That worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @EnoGerguri Yes! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that your json files are not valid. You need to put [] around your objects. Here is how these files should be:

file1.json

```
[
    {
      "seconds": 112,
      "label": "1",
      "value": {
        "time": 15,
        "period": 1576,
        "values": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      },
      "shape": {
        "type": 1,
        "values": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      },
      "size": {
        "type": 1,
        "values": [
          -9,
          10,
          20
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "seconds": 115,
      "label": "2",
      "value": {
        "time": 20,
        "period": 882,
        "values": [
          11,
          82,
          8
        ]
      },
      "shape": {
        "type": 1,
        "values": [
          99,
          8,
          3
        ]
      },
      "size": {
        "type": 3,
        "values": [
          89,
          65,
          -20
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

file2.json

```
[
  {
    "seconds": 532,
    "label": "12",
    "value": {
      "time": 90,
      "period": 4328,
      "values": [
        11,
        2,
        32
      ]
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": 1,
      "values": [
        112,
        2,
        32
      ]
    },
    "size": {
      "type": 1,
      "values": [
        -23,
        9420,
        20
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "seconds": 115,
    "label": "2",
    "value": {
      "time": 20,
      "period": 882,
      "values": [
        11,
        82,
        8
      ]
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": 1,
      "values": [
        942,
        6,
        332
      ]
    },
    "size": {
      "type": 32,
      "values": [
        49,
        125,
        -590
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Also, there are minor errors in your python code. This should work:

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
        result += json.load(infile)

with open("merge.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Note that you should use += instead of append since append will add an entire list of dictionaries as a new item in a list.

Answer (score 0):

file1.json and file2.json should be a list with dictionary object in it like this

```
[{"seconds":112,"label":"1","value":{"time":15,"period":1576,"values":[1,2,3]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[1,2,3]},"size":{"type":1,"values":[-9,10,20]}},
{"seconds":115,"label":"2","value":{"time":20,"period":882,"values":[11,82,8]},"shape":{"type":1,"values":[99,8,3]},"size":{"type":3,"values":[89,65,-20]}}]
```

then you can use below code use `extend` instead of `append`

```
files=['file1.json','file2.json',...]

def merge_JsonFiles(filename):
        result = list()
        for f1 in filename:
            with open(f1, 'r') as infile:
                result.extend(json.load(infile))
    
        with open('counseling3.json', 'w') as output_file:
            json.dump(result, output_file)
    
    merge_JsonFiles(files)
```