# How to merge the content from files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a list of files in a folder, the format of the file name as follows

```
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01-00.txt
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01-01.txt
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01-02.txt
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01-00.txt
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-02-01.txt
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-02-02.txt
```

Inside the file, data is in the format

```
1279067346301321217
1279067346209038337
1279067346343038977
1279067346301333507
```

I wanted to merge all these files to one file(according to date) so the final output should look like

```
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01.txt
coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-02.txt
```

Then I wanted to collect 1000 sample the content from the final the file.

I am not getting any clue to merge the file.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. You can check this answer already provided in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Comment: @MarcS thanks but not exactly

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be found in some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files) but the jist of it is below.

```py
root_filename = "coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01.txt"

with open(root_filename, "w") as root_file:
    for i in range(0, 99): # or whatever you file quantity is
        with open(f"coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01-{i:02}.txt", "r") as temp:
            root_file.write(temp.read())
```

Comment: How can I automate the f"coronavirus-tweet-id-2020-06-01-{i:02}.txt". I wanted to pass the different date here

Comment: Well I guess you could loop the filename. There are plenty of examples out there. Have a look at [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) as well.